Parental Reflective Functioning: meaning of certain score values in the PDI-RF scale
Regarding the mentalization construct of parental reflective functioning, which can be assessed by coding parental development interview for reflective functioning (PDI-RF), can someone briefly describe the meaning of each score (–1 to 9) or at least for the values of the scores 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7?
Just can't find a coding manual where it is written.
